# Name provided not a properly formed account name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Can someone help with another error I'm experiencing?

My create user script is giving me another error.

```
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a  variable as below

    $Username   = $User.ID
    $Password   = $User.BDATE
    $Firstname  = $User.FNAME
    $Lastname   = $User.LNAME
    $Department = $User.GRD
    $Company    = $User.SCHID #This field refers to the OU the user account is to be moved to

    # Choose OU
    switch ($Company)
    {
        "1480" {$OU = 'OU=students,OU=users,ou=hs,dc=clasd,dc=net'}
        "1479" {$OU = 'OU=students,OU=users,ou=elem,dc=clasd,dc=net'}
        "1480" {$Folder = '\\hs-ss\students\hs'}
        "1479" {$Folder = '\\hs-ss\students\elem'}
    }

    #Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file
    New-ADUser `
        -SamAccountName $Username `
        -UserPrincipalName "$Username@clasd.net" `
        -Name $Firstname $Lastname `
        -GivenName $Firstname `
        -Department "$Department" `
        -Company "$Company" `
        -EmailAddress "$Username@clasd.net" `
        -Surname $Lastname `
        -Enabled $True `
        -Scriptpath "login.vbs" `
        -DisplayName "$Firstname $Lastname" `
        -Path $OU `
        -Homedrive "Z" `
        -homedirectory "$Folder\$username" `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "$User.BDATE" -AsPlainText -Force) `
        -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
}
```

My error is:

```
New-ADUser : The name provided is not a properly formed account name
At C:\AD_Scripts\psscripts\user_create.ps1:34 char:9
+         New-ADUser `
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=\\ ,OU=stude...dc=clasd,dc=net:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The name provided is not a properly formed account name,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

**EDIT 1**

If I `Write-Host $Firstname $Lastname` I get "User2 User2" which is correct.

**EDIT 2**

The account still gets created even with that message I receive.

**Edit 3**

I've gone ahead and splatted things like I've been told. I'm still struggling with the same error though. Only this time the user does NOT get created.

```
# Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
 Import-Module activedirectory

 #Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
 $ADUsers = Import-csv userimport.csv
 #Store report in log file in the $log variable
 $log = "log.txt"

 #Set Additional Variables
 $Password = (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "$User.BDATE" -Force)
 $DisplayName = "$User.FNAME+ ' ' + $user.LNAME"
 $Company = $User.SCHID

 # Choose OU

Switch ($Company)
{
    "1480" {$OU = 'OU=students,OU=users,ou=hs,dc=clasd,dc=net'}
    "1479" {$OU = 'OU=students,OU=users,ou=elem,dc=clasd,dc=net'}
    "1480" {$Folder = '\\hs-ss\students\hs'}
    "1479" {$Folder = '\\hs-ss\students\elem'}
}


Write-Host $DisplayName

#Create Hash Table for New User Creation

 $ADUsers = @{

'SamAccountName' = "$User.ID"
'UserPrincipalName' = "$User.ID + '@clasd.net'"
'GivenName' = "$User.FNAME"
'SurName' = "$User.LNAME"
'EmailAddress' = "$User.ID = '@clasd.net'"
'Path' = $OU
'Department' = "$User.GRD"
'Company' = "$User.SCHID"
'AccountPassword' = $Password
'ChangePasswordAtLogon' = $true
'Enabled' = $true
'DisplayName' = "$DisplayName"
'Name' = $Displayname
}

#Call New-ADUser with the parameters Above
Foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
New-ADUser @ADUsers}
```

PS C:\AD_Scripts\psscripts> .\Untitled1.ps1
CN=User2 User2,OU=Students,OU=Users,OU=Elem,DC=clasd,DC=net.FNAME+ ' ' + CN=User2 User2,OU=Students,OU=Users,OU=Elem,DC=clasd,DC=net.LNAME
New-ADUser : The name provided is not a properly formed account name
At C:\AD_Scripts\psscripts\Untitled1.ps1:48 char:1
+ New-ADUser @ADUsers}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=CN\=User2 Us...dc=clasd,dc=net:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The name provided is not a properly formed account name,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Comment: Hello again, first want to ask if you ended up resolving the password problem, just saw your most recent comment a moment ago.  second can you do a `Write-Host $username` just before the `New-ADUser`? to verify that the $UserName variable contains the data you expect?

Comment: try `-Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `

Comment: @AustinFrench your answer still gives me the same error/message

Comment: I see in your second edit that the account is still being created, does the account have the `name` and `distinguishedname` properties populated with the correct info?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio yes everything gets populated correctly

Comment: Well that's odd, try either only defining name or given name and surname rather than all three. Not 100% sure but I think it will generate name if you give it the other two, which may cause an error if both are there

Comment: @MikeGaruccio when I remove name from the equation is wants me to supply the name parameter

Comment: hmm ok sorry wasn't near a pc to test that at the time, I just had a chance to run a few tests on my end and everything seems to be working correctly.. If you haven't already can you try closing out of ISE completely and then re-opening?  have had that fix some random errors in the past.  otherwise are you getting the error on each pass through your CSV or only on "User2"?

Comment: If it were me I'd assign all those parameters as a hashtable so that I could review it before execution `$UserArgs = @{'samAccountName = $UserName;'Name' = "$FirstName $LastName ... }` Then you can review `$UserArgs` before running `New-ADUser @UserArgs`. I find that helps me find mistakes when I get errors like this. Its also safer than using the backtick as a line continuation character if you want to have things laid out line-by-line like that.

Comment: glancing at msdn -Name accepts a paramter like "johnsmith", I would assume the space would be OK... but worth trying without "$first$last"

Comment: Getting it on each pass @MikeGaruccio.  I've tried removing the - name parameter but then it requires me to enter a  value.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated powershell to version 4 and I no longer receive any errors in my original script that I posted. Previously I was using Ver 3