# sudent, invalid name for New-ADUser multi user creation script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm pulling some user info from a .csv to create new users, 
I've splatted the New User Params at the suggestion of someone here

but I'm getting this error

```
New-ADUser : The name provided is not a properly formed account name
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\cyclone-internal-user-sync-1\Bamboo Attributes form a csv.ps1:67 char:17
+                 New-ADUser $NewUserParms -ErrorAction Stop
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=System.Colle...=Cyclone,DC=com:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1315,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

the username variable seems to be correct as far as I know, when it outputs during running of the script its what I assume to be correct format of "firstname.lastname"

I have added trims and a section to remove spaces from usernames. to deal with multipart names such as Van der.... etc

```
#Bamboo Attributes from a .csv

#Enter a path to your import CSV file
$ADUsers = Import-csv 'path'


foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {


        $firstName = $user.FirstName.Trim()
        $surname = $user.Surname.Trim()

        $vaildUsernameFormat = "[^a-zA-Z_.]"                                        # identifies anything that's _not_ a-z or underscore or .
        $username = "($firstName'.'$surname)" -replace $vaildUsernameFormat, ''       #removes anything that isn't a-z

        $DefaultPassword = 'Pa$$w0rd'
        $NewUserParms = @{
                'samAccountName'    = $username;
                'Name'              = "$firstname $surname";
                'DisplayName'       = "$firstname $surname";
                'UserPrincipalName' = "$username@domain.com";
                'GivenName'         = $firstname;
                'Surname'           = $surname;
                'EmailAddress'      = $User.Email;
                'AccountPassword'   = (ConvertTo-SecureString $DefaultPassword -AsPlainText -Force);
                'Enabled'           = $true;
                'Path'              = "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com";

        }




        write-host "$username this is username value"



        #Check if the user account already exists in AD
        if (Get-ADUser -F {
                        sAMAccountName -eq $username
                }) {
                #If user does exist, output a warning message
                Write-Warning "A user account $username has already exist in Active Directory."

        }
        else {
                #If a user does not exist then create a new user account

                New-ADUser $NewUserParms -ErrorAction Stop
        }
}
```

I've removed some of the user attributes just to make this a bit smaller.
here is the.csv as well in case I've messed something up there
[link to .csv file on git](https://github.com/alexhuntinbox/Test1/blob/master/SampleUserAttributes.csv)

Comment: Did any of the accounts get created? Or is it choking on the first one in the list?

Comment: none of the accounts are being made, but it is trying to make all of them it just fails with that error on each one

Comment: Check your PowerShell version with `Get-Host | Select-Object Version`. [This person](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40724927/1202807) was getting this error on PowerShell 3, but stopped getting it on PowerShell 4.

Comment: version number is 5.1.14393.3471

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's something simple. When you use splatting, you need to use the `@` symbol when feeding your hash table to the cmdlet rather than the regular `$`:

```
New-ADUser @NewUserParms -ErrorAction Stop
```

Some more reading [About Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).

Comment: thank, i have more error now haha, but ill make a separate post for that